# Looping through items in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, indexing, foreach

I have an array of objects.

```
ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems();
```

this produces the result:

[MY ARRAY OF OBJECTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAcGW.png)

In the console i can get the result i am looking for by specifying the position of the item like this:

```
ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems()[0].getPosition()
ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems()[1].getPosition()
ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems()[2].getPosition()
```

The result of the above code produces string values e.g "3.4554,43,0".

How can i loop through each item and get the position in my code. just like the above code that i typed in the console. there wont always be 3 objects this is why i cant hard code the above 3  lines.

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [MCVE (**M**inimal, **C**omplete, and **V**erifiable **E**xample)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). 
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778974/how-to-call-items-from-an-array-inside-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a the Array.prototype.forEach() function.  The function will be called for each element in the array, passing in the element as the first parameter.

```
ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems().forEach( function (item) {
  item.getPosition();
  //do something else
});
```

More on ".forEach()"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: could you please help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778974/how-to-call-items-from-an-array-inside-a-function

Comment: can you help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778974/how-to-call-items-from-an-array-inside-a-function

Answer (score 1):

You can use for loop to iterate trough all of them.

```
for(var i=0; i<ABC.getAggregation("V").getItems().length; i++) {
    ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems()[i].getPosition();
}
```

Comment: you're missing () inside your loop. `ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems()[i].getPosition();`

Comment: It says "getItems() is not a function"

Comment: can anyone help me with this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778974/how-to-call-items-from-an-array-inside-a-function

Answer (score 1):

You can treat it like any other array:

```
var myArray = ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems();
for(var i=0; i< myArray.length; i++){
  myArray[i].getPosition(); //Do something with the position.
}
```

Comment: any help with this one? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778974/how-to-call-items-from-an-array-inside-a-function

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach loop to iterate trough all of them.

```
ABC.getAggregation("V").getItems().forEach (item, index) {
  return  ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems()[index].getPosition();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way to iterate through each object in the array is just with a for loop on the array, you don't even need to declare your iterating variable.

ex:

```
var anArray = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

for( i in anArray){  
    console.log('index #: ' + i );
    console.log(anArray[i]);
}
```

will print out all the elements in anArray:

```
index #: 0

one

index #: 1 

two

index #: 2

three
```

Answer (score -2):

**!! Apparently this is a good example of how not to do it :P**

You can assign the items to an array and loop through them like this:

```
var items = ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems();
var returnString = "";
for (var key in items ) {
  if (items .hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var element = items [key];
    returnString += element.getPosition() + ',';
  }
}
returnString = returnString.substring(0, x.length-1);
console.log(returnString);
```

Comment: Why not just for loop?

Comment: how about looping trough arrays with `forEach` or maybe still via `for (var idx = 0, len = items.length; idx < len; ++idx) { ... }` ? But please not via `key in arrayLikeObject`.

Comment: My train of thought was that if .getItems() returns an undefined in the array, we would not want to iterate over that and get undefined errors.

Comment: @TimvanOsch ... but also then it was better testing for the result of `.getItems()` then doing `key in object` with it.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I agree. I've also edited my answer with a warning. I keep my answer so other viewers can see what they should not do.

Comment: can anyone help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38778974/how-to-call-items-from-an-array-inside-a-function