# How to call items from an array inside a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, indexing

I have a function "zoom" which takes the following format:

```
zoom( [a,b,c,d....], [a,b,c,d...] );
```

I also have a for loop which gets me the values that need to go into the zoom array:

```
ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems().forEach( function (item) {
                  var a = item.getPosition().split(";")[0];
                  var b = item.getPosition().split(";")[1];
                  ABC.zoom( [...], [...] );
            });
```

How can I add variables a and b into the arrays of function zoom?

All variable a's must go into the first array and all variables b must go into the second.

Example:

```
 ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems()
 //returns a list of 3 objects
 item.getPosition()
 //returns e.g "0,0,0" for the first item and so on (for all 3)
 item.getPosition().split(";")[0] = "0"
 //now i want to add this to the zoom function.

 var a = item.getPosition().split(";")[0]; 
//this produces three string values "14.5". "4", "8.64"


var b = item.getPosition().split(";")[1];
//this produces three string values "5.7","6.8","1"
```

Now, I want to put these string values into zoom like this:

```
ABC.zoom( [14.5. 4, 8.64], [5.7,6.8,1] );
//note - they're not strings anymore.
```

How can I achieve this result?

Comment: your zoom function at the top seems to accept 4 or more items in each array, at the bottom you pass in 3 - your comments in the code try to explain what the unposted code does, but not very well - I can't get a sense of what the input data is, and how it relates to the required output at all

Comment: If `item.getPosition()` returns a string like `0,0,0` why are you splitting with `;` as the delimiter instead of `,`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot execute the call to `ABC.zoom()` inside the `.forEach()` loop, since you'll only get the whole data set once all iterations have been executed.

I think you need something along those lines:

```
var zoomA = [],
    zoomB = [];

ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems().forEach( function (item) {
  var a = item.getPosition().split(";")[0];
  var b = item.getPosition().split(";")[1];
  zoomA.push(Number(a));
  zoomB.push(Number(b));
});

ABC.zoom(zoomA, zoomB);
```

Please let me know if I somehow misunderstood what you are trying to do.

Comment: i see what you mean. you are right. but my zoom has the format ([ ], [ ]) not [ [ ] , [ ] ]. so zoom[0].push... wont work. how can i make the code run with the format of zoom being ([ ], [ ])

Answer (score 0):

Split return an array of strings, so `item.getPosition().split(";")[0];` will return a string, not three strings. You need to split it again with `,` delimiter, parse the result array to int (you can use `map` function) and pass to zoom function.

Comment: item.getPosition().split(";")[0]; returns 1 string. but there are 3 items in myABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems() hence why i put three strings. it goes through each item in my list. now that i have 3 strings how can i add them to the zoom function.

Comment: I don't know exactly what `getAggregation` does, but:
if above code return `a = ["14.5", "4", "8.64"]` then you can do like this.
`ABC.getAggregation("V")[0].getItems().forEach( function (item) {
                  var a = parseFloat(item.getPosition().split(";")[0]);
                  var b = parseFloat(item.getPosition().split(";")[1]);
            });
 ABC.zoom( a, b );`

Comment: If not, you can create two variable a, b first. Then inside the forEach, push value to a and b, and call zoom after.